# how to deploy rails action as site root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, action, root

in routes.rb, I set a controller and a action as root, it works very well when I visit root in development mode.

now , I try to use nginx  to hook rails app together, seemed nginx.conf need rails public folder which is not the root path set in the routes.rb.

index under public folder only can be a static html, how could I hook nginx with rails action as root?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

nginx is only a webserver - have you installed something like [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) as your app server to run your application in? It's perfectly normal to map the webserver to your public folder but then the application server will process the request and serve back your app for you

Comment: I install thin server, and start thin succsfully. but the guide said that I need set the nginx.conf root as public folder of rails app which is not my root path set in routes.rb. when I visit http://ip:80, it always get a nginx page, not my main page, that is my question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed thin and nginx, and it finally success under ubuntu. I was failed to config nginx in fedora, I think it should be config issue.